# como actualizar correctamente base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando hacer una página web desde donde el usuario logueado pueda modificar sus datos.
No encuentro donde puede estar el fallo, porque la conexión con la base de datos la hace correctamente, pero da error al intentar actualizar la base de datos, y no muestra ninguna modificación.
añado checklogin.php que ya que lo subo, comento que aunque hace bien el login, si pongo un usuario o contraseña incorrecta, queda la pantalla en blanco al entrar en el checklogin. asi que falla por varios sitios.
de antemano agradezco mucho la ayuda, aun estoy empezando con esto. gracias

```
introducir el código aquí


<?php

session_start();

$servername = "xxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$database = "xxxxxx";

$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];
$id= $_SESSION['idusuario']; 


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 echo "Conectado, ";

$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido' , email='$email', contrasena='$contrasena',  WHERE idusuario='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $nick;
    echo " Modificación de datos realizada con éxito";
 echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=/welcome.php'></head>";
}

else {
    echo " Error, imposible actualizar " ;
    echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=/datos.php'></head>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

añado checklogin.php

```
<?php
 include("conexion.php");
session_start();
?>

<?php


$nick = $_POST["nick"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// no necesario   echo "Conectado, ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick='$nick' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $nick = $row['nick'];
        $contrasena = $row['contrasena'];

        //check to see if the match

  if($nick != $nick || $contrasena != $contrasena) {

       echo  "Incorrect password or username!";
       echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=/index.php'></head>";
} 
 elseif($nick == $nick && $contrasena == $contrasena ) {

        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $nick;
                $_SESSION['apellido']=$row['apellido'];
                $_SESSION['nombre']=$row['nombre'];
                $_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];
                $_SESSION['idusuario']=$row['idusuario'];

      //  echo "You're Logged In! ";
      //  echo $_SESSION['usuario'];

     echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=/welcome.php'></head>";

}
 else {
        echo "That user doesn't exist!";
}

}
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: cual es el error que muestra?

Comment: me salta al else, y me muestra el mensaje de no se ha podido actualizar

Comment: Creo que te sobra una coma en tu query después de contrasena. Prueba a ver

Comment: arreglado, ese era el fallo, la coma, pero cuando probe no habia actualizado. gracias!! Ahora el único problema es que al actualizar los datos me hace logout, y pierdo el login, tengo que volver a loguearme

Comment: La variable $nick no la veo declarada antes de la condición, la coma que esta delate del **where** debes borrarla. Con respecto a la redireccion realiza el cambio que el compañero Mario Guiber te sugiere.

Answer (score 4):

Dejo aquí una respuesta para que se pueda votar.

Vamos por partes. Como te he comentado en el comentario de arriba, para solicitar la query de `UPDATE`, tan solo habría que borrar la coma que está al lado de `contrasena`, antes del `WHERE`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido' , email='$email', contrasena='$contrasena' WHERE idusuario='$id'";
```

Para hacer el redireccionamiento después de hacer la modificación cambiaría la línea:

```
echo "<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2; url=/welcome.php'></head>";
```

Por esta otra:

```
header('Location: welcome.php');
```

Asegurándote que en ese archivo tengas `session_start();` para poder seguir trabajando con sesiones.

Espero que sea de utilidad!

Comment: si cambio esa linea, se queda en " Modificación de datos realizada con éxito",  despues, en welcome.php tengo : <?php
   include('checklogin.php');
   include("conexion.php");
session_start();
?>   que es la misma que cuando hago login , y al hacer loguin me lee bien la sesion, peor al modificar datos no, tal como comente se desloguea

Comment: Puedes añadir a la pregunta el contenido que tienes en checklogin.php? A ver sí vemos algo raro

Comment: añadido el checklogin, tal como comente arriba, falla al meter un usuario o cotraseña incorrecta

Comment: No sé hasta qué punto es rentable es utilizar la misma variable para distintas cosas. Intente no utilizar dos veces nick o dos veces contrasena